# Apache URL rewrite UUID v1

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, uuid

How do you rewrite a 36 character [v1 UUID](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid) *precisely* with maximal-checking using RewriteRule?

`UUID() returns a value that conforms to UUID version 1 as described in RFC 4122. The value is a 128-bit number represented as a utf8 string of five hexadecimal numbers in aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee format:`

---

Please give something better than this:
`RewriteRule ^([A-z0-9\-]{36})$ index.php?uuid=$1 [L,QSA]`

Comment: Can you please show some examples of uuid's?

Comment: They are in the format above... so for example `d6b802fa-bf64-11ea-9d45-0a7e89a26b17` is one of many many possibilities

Comment: I added the answer; please check once and do let me know; if you need something else in regards to this post.

Answer (score 1):

You may try:

```
^[a-fA-F0-9]{8}-(?:[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-){3}[a-fA-F0-9]{12}$
```

**Explanation of the above regex:**

- **`^, $`** - Represents start and end of the line respectively.
- **`[a-fA-F0-9]{8}`** - According to the docs; **as a utf8 string of five hexadecimal numbers**; so it is good to allow only hex characters. Therefore; first string before `-` is 8 characters long hex value.
- **`(?:[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-){3}`** - Represents a non-capturing group matching hex characters 4 times followed by a `-` and the whole pattern repeats exactly 3 times.
- **`[a-fA-F0-9]{12}`** - Represents hex characters exactly 12 times.
- **`$0`** - For the matching part you may use 0th captured group since there is no special capturing.

---

[image: Pictorial Representation]

### Regex demo