# React Router Dom v5 : regex path of a GUID / UUID is not recognised

Tags: regex, reactjs, react-router

react-router-dom version 5.1.2

---

Example route:

```
/user/:guid
```

Example guid:

```
2d88abfd-35a2-4481-91c9-800ecc67b346
```

Example route with guid regex:

```
/user/:guid([0-9a-f]{8}-([0-9a-f]{4}\-){3}[0-9a-f]{12})
```

I'm unable to get a match with the above. To test my sanity to see if basic regex paths work, I did a simple number only regex, that works fine, maybe I'm not escaping correctly?

Comment: Try without groups, `/user/:guid([0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12})`

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62788455/7571182) answer might help

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you star! Thanks a lot mate, can't believe I didn't think to try that doh!

Comment: For anyone coming across this today: react-router-dom no longer supports regex. See FAQs: https://reactrouter.com/en/6.14.0/start/faq#what-happened-to-regexp-routes-paths

However, the regex shouldn't be necessary in this case. The route segment (everything after the final /) will be stored in params.guid, it will be stored in the params. See docs: https://reactrouter.com/en/6.14.0/route/route#dynamic-segments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though the pattern in the react router [cannot contain inner grouping constructs](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp/issues/95).

They mention that "*`(?:` will be allowed to be nested in the next major release."*

So, probably, you will be able to use

```
/user/:guid([0-9a-f]{8}(?:-[0-9a-f]{4}){3}-[0-9a-f]{12})
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

If this is not implemented in your version, just repeat the pattern part you quantified:

```
/user/:guid([0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12})
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```